# Couchbase custom deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, couchbase

I have a class that I need to serialize to JSON in Couchbase in a custom manner. So I do something like:

```
var converters = new[] { new CustomConverter() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, jsonConverters.ToArray()); 
var result = _couchbaseClient.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Add, id, json);
```

But how can I deserialize this again, using the `CustomConverter`? I want to retrieve the JSON and do the deserializing myself. I realize there's a `ExecuteGet` method, but I'd like to work via a view.

Is this possible?

I've tried add my converter to the `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` but it doesn't seem to use it. I keep getting a `JsonSerializationException`. I'm guessing Couchbase resets the settings, or uses its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into the Couchbase code, I found it. Couchbase has some extension methods which use their own settings. You can see this [on GitHub](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/src/Couchbase/Extensions/CouchbaseClientExtensions.cs):

```
public static class CouchbaseClientExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings;

    static CouchbaseClientExtensions()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new DocumentIdContractResolver()
            };
    }

    // ...

    private static string SerializeObject(object value)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value,
                                Formatting.None,
                                JsonSerializerSettings);
        return json;
    }
}
```

So you can add your own converters like this:

```
foreach (var jsonConverter in jsonConverters)
{
    if (!CouchbaseClientExtensions
             .JsonSerializerSettings
             .Converters.Any(x => x.GetType() == jsonConverter.GetType()))
    {
        CouchbaseClientExtensions
            .JsonSerializerSettings
            .Converters.Add(jsonConverter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm no longer working with Couchbase and it seems there code has changed or been restructured. Check out these files to see if it helps you: [DefaultSerializer](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/97abd1adee687543b9f6434cff1cd7fda90436e6/Src/Couchbase/Core/Serialization/DefaultSerializer.cs) and [ClientConfiguration](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/1ce46c243a520f901a94e557c6e396e15de909f1/Src/Couchbase/Configuration/Client/ClientConfiguration.cs)

Comment: Exactly, the solution right now (for future readers) is make your own serializer implementing ITypeSerializer, you can still using newtonSoft json, but you need to wrap it in your own implementation. http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/june/using-jil-for-custom-json-serialization-in-the-couchbase-.net-sdk